# PHP | Custom Indian Money format function doesn't consider decimals

Tags: php, decimal, money-format

I have this function which converts a number to Indian money format.

```
function IND_money_format($money)
{
$len = strlen($money);
$m = '';
$money = strrev($money);
for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
    if(( $i==3 || ($i>3 && ($i-1)%2==0) )&& $i!=$len){
        $m .=',';
    }
    $m .=$money[$i];
}
return strrev($m);
}
```

Output is fine if I give whole numbers as input and not decimals.
ex:

```
3 => 3
30 => 30
300 => 300
3000  => 3,000
459600 =>  4,59,600
```

But if I give a decimal number the output gets corrupt
ex:

```
379.50 => 37,9.5
```

*How can I fix this?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the right way, but It seems to be working as of now.
what I'm doing is

- extract the decimal part from number as string
- remove any zeros before decimal point (`0.5` becomes `.5`)
- simply concatenate the decimal string to final answer.

So the function becomes something like this:

```
public function IND_money_format($money){
        $decimal = (string)($money - floor($money));

        $money = floor($money);
        $len = strlen($money);
        $m = '';
        $money = strrev($money);
        for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
            if(( $i==3 || ($i>3 && ($i-1)%2==0) )&& $i!=$len){
                $m .=',';
            }
            $m .=$money[$i];
        }

        $a = strrev($m);
        // $a = $decimal;
        $decimal = preg_replace("/0\./i", ".", $decimal);

        if( $decimal != '0'){
        $a = $a.$decimal;
        }

        return $a;
    }
```

**Can anybody please review this code ?**